# How do I reverse my for loop when I'm parsing a text file (python)

Tags: python

I have a for loop which iterates through a text file (in this case actually a Python file) and it is trying to extract all the functions (looking for the word `def`). Once it finds that word it starts recording lines until it hits a blank space (which I'm using to denote the end of the function).

My problem is that I want to backup once I hit a `def` in the file and record any comments that might come before the function. Ex: `# This function does the following...` etc. I want to backup until I no longer hit a hash.

How would I look backwards with this loop I have written?

```
for (counter,line) in enumerate(visible_texts):
    line= line.encode('utf-8')
# if line doesn't contain def then ignore it
    if "def" in line and infunction== 0:
        match = re.search(r'\def (\w+)', line.strip())
        line = line.split ("def")[1]    
        print "Recording start of the function..."
        # Backup to see if there's any hashes above it (until the end of the hashes) ** how do I do this **
```

An example of output I would want at the end would be:

```
# This function was created by Thomas
# This function print a pass string into the function    
def printme( str ):
       "This prints a passed string into this function"
       print str
       return
```

Comment: Using `ast.parse` might be suitable for this (although probably overkill!)

Comment: Using `if "def" in line` could lead to false positives if you have variable names that have "def" in them. It is probable better to `strip()` each line and then use `if line.startswith("def")`.

Comment: This is a rather crude way to parse python code. It might be sufficient for your needs, but for the general case I'd second the `parse` suggestion.

Comment: Ok I'll look into the `parse` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't back up; record comments regardless, until you hit another line. If it's not a `def` line, discard the comments gathered:

```
comments = []
for (counter, line) in enumerate(visible_texts):
    if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
        comments.append(line)
    elif "def" in line and not infunction:
        comment = '\n'.join(comments)
        comments = []
        # rest of your code
    else:
        comments = []
```

Comment: Ok that's a good idea! Is that best practices in general? To not go backwards?

Comment: Absolutely; much simpler gathering the information when it is passing by already. Why go back for that when you don't know how far back you have to go?

Comment: Thanks makes a lot of sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module to [parse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) python code.

You should get into the habit of using [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) instead of comments to describe a function.

One of the advantages is that the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module  can fish out these docstrings using [`ast.get_docstring()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.get_docstring).